# Better way to create multiple notlike if statement

Tags: powershell, if-statement

This if statement doesn't match anything for some reason even though the output in the CSV has the data $MemberName in the cell.

```
if($MemberName -notlike "Administrator" -or $MemberName -notlike "Domain Admins" -or $MemberName -notlike "Workstation Admin"){
                Add-Content -Path $OutPutFile -Value "$Computer, $LocalGroupName, SUCCESS, $MemberType, $MemberDomain, $MemberName"
            }
```

Also is there a more effeciet way to write the if statement? I only want to add the row IF the $MemberDomain and $MemberName DON'T MATCH the following sets of criteria:

```
$MemberDomain    $MemberName
LocalUser   AND  Administrator
DomainGroup AND  Workstation Admin
DomainGroup AND  Domain Admins
```

Somethinng like:

```
if(($MemberName -notlike "Administrator" -and $MemberDomain -notlike "LocalUser") -or ($MemberName -notlike "Domain Admins" -and $MemberDomain -notlike "DomainGroup") -or ($MemberName -notlike "Workstation Admin" -and $MemberDomain -notlike "DomainGroup")) { do something }
```

This is what works but I think there is a more efficient way of testing for the two values together.

```
$ExcludedNames = ("Administrator","Workstation Admin","Domain Admins")
$ExcludedMemberTypes = ("LocalUser","DomainGroup")

if(($ExcludedNames -contains $MemberName) -and ($ExcludedMemberTypes -contains $MemberType) ){
    } else {
    Add-Content -Path $OutPutFile -Value "$Computer, $LocalGroupName, SUCCESS, $MemberType, $MemberDomain, $MemberName"
    }
```

The issues that that I want to match both at true together. For example the combination of "DomainGroup and Administrator" would be true with the code above and it should be false when only LocalUser and Administrator should be true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you don't need wildcard-matching, you could use a `switch` and `-notcontains`

```
$Success = switch($MemberDomain)
{
    "LocalUser" {"Administrator" -ne $MemberName}
    "DomainGroup" {"Workstation Admin","Domain Admins" -notcontains $MemberName}
}

if($Success){
    Add-Content # ...
}
```

In PowerShell 3.0 and above, you can also use the equivalent `-notin` operator, might be a little more intuitive:

```
$MemberName -notin "Workstation Admin","Domain Admins"
```

Comment: Interesting. Never thought of switch. I'll have to read up on it.